# Nested dictionary or list using given unindent data using Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tree

Hi I have given below data but its unindent only using total keyword I can find the right nodes and can build tree structure.
Input:

```
Current Assets  
Cash  
Checking 583961  
Savings 224600  
Petty Cash 89840  
Total Cash 898402  
Accounts Receivable 3593607  
Work in Process 589791  
Other Current Assets  
Prepaid Rent 164593  
Prepaid Liability Insurance 109728  
Total Other Current Assets 274321  
Total Current Assets 274321
```

I am looking for below Output:

```
{
    "Current Assets": {
        "Cash": {
            "Checking": 583961,
            "Savings": 224600,
            "Petty Cash": 89840,
            "Total Cash": 898402
        },
        "Accounts Receivable": 3593607,
        "Work in Process": 589791,
        "Other Current Assets": {
            "Prepaid Rent": 164593,
            "Prepaid Liability Insurance": 109728,
            "Total Other Current Assets": 274321
        },
        "Total Current Assets": 5356121
    }
}
```

I tried recursion and node concept but nothing worked, It will be great if someone can help me on that trying to achieve using Python.

Rules:

As an example :
Actually `work in process`  is not sub item of `Account Receivable' Its item of` current asset only.
As "work in progress" have digit at its end hence no children of it.

As per input data Cash does not have any numeric value at end hence such entries will have child/children,

cash is ending once having total cash with numeric value.

There will not be any children of work in process or Accounts Receivable as they are ending with Numeric value at end

Comment: You haven't given enough information. Why, for example, should `Work in Process` be its own item and not a sub item of `Accounts Receivable`? There's nothing automatic that will know that. Since you didn't show what you have tried, we can't even infer your thinking about this.

Comment: What are the numbers like `1000`, or `1320` and where did they come from?

Comment: Hi @Mark Thans for reviewing the same , Actually `work in process`  is not sub item of `Account Receivable' Its item of `current asset only. 
As "work in progress" have digit at his end hence no children of it.

Comment: But how do you know it doesn't belong under Cash then?

Comment: Hi @Mark `Cash` is end with `total cash'. Hence `Accounts Receivable` and `work in process` will be new immediate children of `Current Assets`. There will not be any children of `work in process` or `Accounts Receivable` as they are ending with Numeric value at end

Comment: Hi @dafrandle That was the typo , I have removed it.

Comment: ok 2 questions: 1. is the input plain text? 2. Can we assume that it will ALWAYS have all of these options and that they will be in the same order?

Comment: Yes @dafrandle input is plaintext, actually rules are same but options will change based on next load. Rules like node will have children if not ending with numeriC value. And such node will end with "Total ..." . There will not be any children. If it's have numeric value at end.

Comment: To clarify, by options I mean the text like `Current Assets` and `Prepaid Rent` - not the following numbers

Comment: Also, if I'm understating you correctly, you're saying that the output should nest one layer deeper whenever it runs into a line that doesn't have a number. If this is the case, then everything from `Accounts Receivable` and down would be children of `Cash` rather than `Current Assets`

Comment: Whenever a line is coming with number means  it will not have any child. But if not have number then it will have child and it will end once have Total ... Line is coming ..And yes order will remain same.. means cash will end with total cash and next line after total cash will be sibling of cash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive function or just use a stack to keep track of the nesting. The basic rule is:

- No number: increase nesting
- Starts with "Total": decrease nesting.

With a stack, it might look like:

```
import re

s = '''Current Assets  
Cash  
Checking 583961  
Savings 224600  
Petty Cash 89840  
Total Cash 898402  
Accounts Receivable 3593607  
Work in Process 589791  
Other Current Assets  
Prepaid Rent 164593  
Prepaid Liability Insurance 109728  
Total Other Current Assets 274321  
Total Current Assets 274321'''


def nest(items):
    res = {}
    stack = [res]
    for item in items:
        components = re.findall(r'(^.*?) (\d+)', item)
        if not components: # no numbers
            cur = {}
            stack[-1][item.strip()] = cur
            stack.append(cur)
        else:
            label, nums = components[0]
            stack[-1][label.strip()] = int(nums)
            if label.startswith("Total"): # end of subdict
                stack.pop()
    return res
        
nest(s.split('\n'))
```

This will return:

```
{
  'Current Assets': {
     'Cash': {
           'Checking': 583961,
           'Savings': 224600,
           'Petty Cash': 89840,
           'Total Cash': 898402
      },
      'Accounts Receivable': 3593607,
      'Work in Process': 589791,
      'Other Current Assets': { 
           'Prepaid Rent': 164593,
           'Prepaid Liability Insurance': 109728,
           'Total Other Current Assets': 274321
      },
      'Total Current Assets': 274321
  }
}
```